# bad request in response to RTSP client SETUP request

Tags: rtsp, rtp, bad-request

I'm imlempenting a RTSP client over TCP to communicate with the live555MediaServer .

The problem is that the server replies with "bad request 400" to my SETUP request

Could any one help me please ?

this is my setup request

"SETUP rtsp://192.168.121.133:8554/test.mpg RTSP/1.0\r\nCSeq: 3\r\nTransport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=9000-9001\r\n\r\n";

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your command:

- Take a look at the URL your are using in SETUP command, it should be the same (for each media stream, audio and video) you received as a reply to your DESCRIBE command.
- You are actually setting up RTP over UDP, not TCP. RTP/AVP defaults to UDP (RFC2326, 12.39). TCP SETUP command should look something like: "SETUP ... RTSP/1.0\r\n\CSeq:...\r\nTransport: RTP/AVP/TCP;interleaved=0-1\r\n\r\n". Command details are described in RFC2326, 12.39